# Can making image a background slow down the working of the page

Tags: html, css

I have created my own website, not much complicated. But when I change the background to image from a simple color everything runs very slow on the site, all the animation and everything.

Working CSS Code:

```
body{    
    color:#eee; 
        background-color: grey;      

}
```

CSS that makes website slow:

```
body{

    color:#eee;
    background-image:url("images/bodyImage3.jpg");
        background-size: 1400px;

}
```

Comment: So the image is only 180Kb? And its making the page load slowly?

Comment: @ZachL Yeah I dont know why, its pretty easily loadable for my target visitors so I am not bothered about people who have slow connection. And strangely when I put the image on side of a page and match the background color of the page according to the background of image it loads very smoothly. The image size is still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is also worth mentioning expires-headers, which will allow clients browsers to cache the background image so they don't have to download it every time they visit your site. This won't improve performance the first time, but on subsequent visits users should notice a significant improvement. This site has lists of improvements you can make to speed your site up, including some information on expires, which should get you started.

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 8):

Yes it will. Try **background-position: fixed**, might help.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, a 1400px image can slow down a site.

Comment: Is there a way to not let this happen. Its only 180Kb in size though.

Comment: *only*?!  It sounds unnecessarily large.

Comment: I don't think thats excessive, especially for a full background image on an otherwise simple page

Comment: I agree with @cimmanon. I just read [this article](http://blog.chriszacharias.com/page-weight-matters). I have a decent internet connection, but someone less fortunate visiting your site would have to wait *four minutes* just to download the background image(!). Everyone wins if you chose to use a CSS3 gradient or a plain old color. Think really, really hard whether the superflous 200k is worth the tax on your users. Maybe it is, but make that an informed decision.

Comment: @bookcasey Yeah but the background image is the whole theme of my website. I worked really hard on the design. I guess il have to find a way to compress the image.